# How to reset scroll settings?

Tags: modeling

I searched for the answer in another post that recommended shift+B to reset scroll lock. I tried it and it still felt strange to navigate, unlike a new file. I can shift+B, then select a window to work on a certain area and then when I change the area, I can select a new window with shift+B. I didn't have to do that before, I could work on all areas fluently. Here's the file where it occurs: [image]

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm fine with shift+B because I select a box and don't need to do it as often as expected. Of course, I'm still open for ideas.

Comment: You can use Numpad Dot to center the view on your selection, and Origin (or Home) key to center the view on your whole object (or your whole scene if your in Object mode)

Answer (score 0):

In your modeling tab everything seems working.

With similar problems try view > align view > view lock clear
or
search for "view lock clear" in search tab → apply.